# Realm Model Relationship

Tags: java, android, database, realm

Is it possible to have model like this ?

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
private String id;
private String name;
private RealmList<Dog> dogs;
private RealmList<Toy> toys;
}

public class Dog extends RealmObject {
private String id;
private String name;
private String color;
private RealmList<Toy> toys;
}

public class Toy extends RealmObject {
private String id;
private String name;
}
```

the relationship that i want between these models are Person have can have multiple dogs, and a dogs can have multiple toys. But i want a Person can track deh Toy too and a person can have multiple toys. please help

Comment: Does a person own toys directly, or only transitively through their dogs?

Comment: actually, basen on my activity i need to create a person object first.. then automatically create toys, after that i create a dog.. a dog can have many toys, i use checklist for my toys to mapping it with the dog.

Comment: This sounds a bit muddled, then, if there is an implicit assumption that a given dog's toys must be a subset of those belonging to that dog's owner.  You could handle such a requirement programmatically, maybe, but as far as I can tell, Realm provides no means to enforce it.

Comment: hmm it just an example with those models.. actually, i create something like billsplit apps . once i create a bill, i define how many person is responsible for that bill.. then i need to create a menu or billdetail, for one bill detail can contains more than one people. are you get my question?

Answer (score 1):

Those models are valid in Realm, but we do not enforce any transitive constraints. If you think of Realm as just an object graph, you should get the idea on what rules you need to enforce yourself.

So if if a Person is only allowed to have Toys that are held by Dogs owned by the Person, you will have to enforce that yourself.

Comment: so do you have any suggestions for this ? because in this apps.. a person can track his own toys and they can manage a dog with many toys.

Comment: Have getter and setters that enforce the constraints would be my choice, but I would think really hard it is really necessary for the Person to keep track of Toys, when those toys can already be found by just looping over all Dogs.

Comment: because my activity is like list of person, a person define his toys first.. after that, a dog will be added and connect to the toys ..

Comment: Why not just have a reference from Dog -> Person, then the Dog can fetch Toys directly from the Person?